# This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression in sql query

Tags: sql-server

I know that this type of question is duplicate but I didnt find accurate answer of this problem. So thats why I post it.

So, my question is that when I am running the sql query in sql server at that time it shows the heading error. I find many of things but didnt work.

Here is my query,

```
select 
    trandate, shortdescr, ref as BillNo,
    f.companyname, h.brnchname,
    tranno, AccName,
    sum(dramount) as NetAmount, sum(SGST) GstAmt,
    sum(CGST) CstAmt, sum(IGST) IGstAmt, s.SeriesName 
from 
    (select 
         trandate, shortdescr, ref, dramount, CompanyID,
         brnchid, accountid, refaccountid, tranno, seriesid, 
         case 
            when accountid = (select top 1 gcsysdescription 
                              from systemparameters 
                              where gcsysvar = 'SGST') 
               then dramount - cramount 
               else 0 
        end as SGST, 
        case  
           when accountid = (select top 1 gcsysdescription 
                             from systemparameters 
                             where gcsysvar = 'CGST' ) 
              then dramount - cramount 
              else 0  
        end as CGST, 
        case 
           when accountid = (select top 1 gcsysdescription 
                             from systemparameters 
                             where gcsysvar = 'IGST' ) 
              then dramount - cramount 
              else 0  
        end as IGST, 
        case 
           when srno = 1 --=(select top 1 gcsysdescription from systemparameters where gcsysvar='IGST' ) 
              then (select accmas.accountname 
                    from accountdet accdet 
                    left outer join accountmaster accmas on accmas.accountid = accdet.accountid 
                    where accdet.srno = 1 and accdet.seriesid = 19) 
        end as AccName
    from 
        accountdet) as abc 
left outer join 
    companymaster F on abc.CompanyID = F.companyid 
left outer join 
    brnchmst H on abc.brnchid = H.brnchid 
left outer join 
    Accountmaster a on abc.accountid=a.accountid
left outer join 
    SeriesMaster s on abc.SeriesID=s.SeriesID 
where
    abc.companyid = 37
    and abc.brnchid in (7, 9, 8, 3, 4) 
    and abc.seriesid = 19
    and convert(varchar(10), trandate, 112) >= '20170920' 
    and convert(varchar(10), trandate, 112) <= '20180331' 
    and a.EntryType <> 'D' 
    and abc.dramount <> 0
group by 
    trandate, shortdescr, ref, f.companyname, h.brnchname, tranno, s.seriesname, AccName
```

Please help me to solve this issues.

Thank You.

Comment: You have at least one of those subqueries returning more than 1 row. Most likely it is the one there that doesn't have a top 1. For all the others you have top 1 but no order by so you have no way of ensuring which row you will get. You also have nonSARGable predicates in your where clause because you are converting all your dates to a varchar. Why not convert the string literal to a date instead so you can utilize indexes on trandate?

Comment: what is the table schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your subquery

```
select accmas.accountname from accountdet accdet LEFT OUTER JOIN accountmaster accmas
ON accmas.accountid= accdet.accountid where accdet.srno = 1 and accdet.seriesid = 19
```

sometimes return more than one row. You should change predicates in `where` or add `TOP(1)...ORDER BY`.